# npm can't be found on hyper-v / ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, node.js, ubuntu-20.04, npm

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V with WSL2 and installed nodejs by doing this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

When I did `node -v` I got `v14.13.1`.

When I do `npm -v` I got a "no such file or directory" error.

I thought npm was supposed to be installed when nodejs was installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `/usr/local/bin/npm` as well. This should do it.

Otherwise, install `npm`package by

`sudo apt-get install npm`

Comment: I tried to do `sudo apt-get install npm` and got a bunch of errors: https://pastebin.com/TPscQBeR. /usr/local/bin/npm is not a file or directory that exists

Comment: May be before issuing the command make a `sudo apt-get update`. I could not see your error on `pastebin`